# File format for saving and reading messages

Tags: java, file

So in short: I need a file format that I can read messages from, the file needs to be friendly to people so they can edit it, it needs to support comments.

I've tried .yml and did not really liked.

I like using .xml but writing parsers is a pain to do, .json would be perfect, but it does not support comments. Also it would be nice if file format would support '&' charachter, because right now I need to replace it with '§'

```
<!-- No permission message -->
<message id="0">
    <msg lang="EN" prefix="true">§7You do not have permission to execute this command!</msg>
    <msg lang="SI" prefix="true">§7Nimas dovoljenja za uporabo te komande!</msg>
</message>
```

programing language is Java, but that probably does not matter.

Comment: This is for internationalization/localization, right? If these formats dont work, [does gettext fit your needs](https://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/a-quick-gettext-tutorial.html)?

Comment: Why not use a Java `.properties` file? And in your example, the proper solution to handle `&` would be to escape it to `&amp;`, and give your users an edit tool that handles XML correctly instead of asking them to manually encode XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## XLIFF

Looks like your content is representing resources for localization.

A standard file format for localization files is [XLIFF (XML Localization Interchange File Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF), built on [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Java offers many excellent tools for reading and writing XML. And I expect you could find some Java-based tools specifically for XLIFF.

[There are various tools](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xliff%20editors&t=ipad&ia=qa) meant to help people edit their localizations, using XLIFF as the written file format. That is the purpose of XLIFF, to be a standard format for the interchange of localization data between various tools and platforms.

I’ve not used any of these, but found a list: Poedit, PoEditor, Qt Linguist, Brightec editor, OmegaT, Virtaal, KDE Localize, XLIFF Translator, Transolution. And, [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120430210001/http://xliff-tools.freedesktop.org/wiki/Resources) is an old list, likely outdated.